# VMWare Workstation Pro Copy paste is not working from Host to guest

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I am using ***VMware® Workstation 12 Pro***. When i try to copy and paste from Host to Guest, the function is not working.

**Host OS** : Windows 10 Enterprise.
**Guest OS** : Windows 7 Ultimate.
**Network** : Bridged (Directly Connect to Physical Network)

But, reverse is working, it means if copy and paste some thing from Guest to Host is working.

I have removed and re-installed the VMWare Tools, which suggested on some of the forums, but it didn't help.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution works for me under Windows 10 so I hope it works for you as well under Windows 7.  Follow the below steps to copy and paste your source code from a programming editor like Visual Studio from one VMWare Workstation to another every time. This process also allows me to copy from my host PC of Windows 10 to a VMWare Workstation running Windows 10 as well.

Prior to this copy and paste would not work without manual administrator setup every time I needed to launch VMWare Workstation for Windows 10. Note: after completing the steps if the VMWare Workstation application is running you will need to shut it down (not just the virtual machine) then re-open the application followed by re-opening your virtual machine(s) for the settings to take effect:

[image]

Comment: Apologies for late reply and thanks for your comment. This solution works.

Comment: Unfortunately, for all the coorporate environments where running as administrator is not possible, this solution doesn't work. Christ, I hate VMWare.

Comment: 2021 UPDATE: This fix still works after an upgrade from VMWare WS Pro 16.1 to 16.1.2 broke copy/paste between Windows 10 host and Windows 10 guest.

Answer (score 0):

VMware workstation version 16+ this might work for older version as well.

1- Under VM tab click on Grab input. Shortcut is ctrl + G (**Test and see if it is fixed, then you are done.**)
[image]

2- **If step 1  was not sufficient** => Under VM tab click on setting. then you have two tabs : Hardware and Option
2.1. Click on Options
[image]

2.2 Then click on Guest Isolation. Make sure Enable copy paste is selected. (you
can also Enable drag and drop.)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution in Workstation 15: add or change following lines in your .vmx file of virtual machine image

isolation.tools.copy.disable = "FALSE"

isolation.tools.dnd.disable = "FALSE"

isolation.tools.paste.disable = "FALSE"

isolation.tools.hgfs.disable = "FALSE"

then restart guest

Answer (score 0):

Go to VMWare menu -> reinstall VMWare Tools -> press Windows key+R -> type d:\setup.exe and click ok to install the required VMware tools which is needed to enable the copy paste functionality.
I tried many things it was not working, even though the guest isolation copy/paste options were by default selected.

But after resintall VMWare Tools it asked me to restart the VM and after that it is working as expected both from and TO VM